# iOS Settings in Unity3D

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the settings panel on ios devices to display my settings. I have read these sources on the topic;

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/23699-App-Settings
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/40506/ios-application-in-the-settings-panel.html

This is not a game being developed, and in-app settings are not suitable. If you want to question this choice, then simply the people paying for the application have listed it as a fixed explicit requirement and are not willing to change this requirement.

The issue that I am currently having is that, despite having a completed Settings.bundle, I am unable to correctly recieve my settings on an iOS device.

The source code can be found below. The confusing part is that "manual_session_control" and "ignore_screen_locks" are registering present when using;

```
PlayerPrefs.HasKey(...);
```

But when calling .GetString() of .GetInt, empty strings or 0 are returned. There is no PlayerPrefs.GetBool().

Also, the other values are returning false when calling PlayerPrefs.HasKey(...); Can anybody shed some clarification on this issue. I am on Unity 4.2.1.

### Settings plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Configurator</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
        <string>None</string>
        <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
        <string>No</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>127.0.0.1</string>
        <key>IsSecure</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>server_ip</string>
        <key>KeyboardType</key>
        <string>URL</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Host Address</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Host Port</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>4782</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>server_port</string>
        <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
        <string>No</string>
        <key>KeyboardType</key>
        <string>NumberPad</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Manual Session Control</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>manual_session_control</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <false/>
        <key>TrueValue</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>FalseValue</key>
        <string>false</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Theme</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>theme</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>Basic</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Debug</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Ignore Screen Locks</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>ignore_screen_locks</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>TrueValue</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>FalseValue</key>
        <string>false</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Show Screen Log</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>show_screen_log</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <false/>
        <key>TrueValue</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>FalseValue</key>
        <string>false</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### Unity Code

```
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
IP = PlayerPrefs.GetString("server_ip");
Port = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("server_port");
ManualSessionControl = PlayerPrefs.GetString("manual_session_control") == "true" ? true : false;
IgnoreScreenLock = PlayerPrefs.GetString("ignore_screen_locks") == "true" ? true : false;
Theme = PlayerPrefs.GetString("theme");
```